# Is there a way to have Rails development mode cache everything except view templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`config.cache_classes = false` puts Rails in develpoment mode and reloads the application code on every request.

But this makes requests really slow.

Is there a middle-ground option, where you can cache everything except view templates? Often I just need view templates reloaded while tweaking the design, but I don't need to reload any other part of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Active Reload Gem](https://github.com/paneq/active_reload). It allows your code to be cached and reloads only those which have changed.

Makes page loads under development much faster.